# insert datetime and replace "space" to ":" in detailsview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Is it possible to insert the datetime like "15 00" instead of "15:00" inside my detailsview?
For example I type 15 00 in Detailsview and in saves as 15:00 in my GridView_Table(sql).

Comment: you mean...web form? not familiar with that but if you have the direct access to the datetime you can do something like .ToString(format) or you can write a javascript to clean that up

Comment: Yeah Asp.net Website. I have a gridview with detailsview, which bound with SQL Database. Such tables like work from or work till I have to fill with datetime, but everytime i have to type 0:00 with ":" and its uncomfortably :( And unfortunatelly I dont know JS, Im learning asp.net and c#. I dont wait for somebody who will do my work, but I just have to know the way, which I need to looking for ))

Comment: that sounds like web form to me. It is old stuff and is being abandoned by MS. I would suggest you to learn MVC instead of Web Form if you are just starting. You will have way more freedom than Web Form

Comment: well, I use this one http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Bezymyannyj.1414629397.jpg and hm, what do you mean about more freedom? what are the differences there? sry for question, which i easily can find on the internet. 1 sentence is more clear than tons of text =)

Comment: Web form abstracted out the underlying logic for html and javascript, which limited the number of things you could do. By doing MVC you have the full control over what you want to do but you need to do a bit more work. And Web form is doing post back with javascript for all the events which is extremely bad for the server since it has to process all the requests...

Comment: thanks for advise, I'll take a look on this thing after my currently project))

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Steve: web forms is not being abandoned by Microsoft. You should learn something before speaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom date format in your gridview you use the DataFormatString attribute on your BoundField something like

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="ModifiedDate" SortExpression="ModifiedDate" DataFormatString="{0:H m}" />
```

H in the format string: The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.
m in the format string: The minute, from 0 through 59

You can use HH mm instead of your want 0 to be 00 for both minutes and hours.

And btw someone inviting you to use something else when you ask a question about asp.net is a bit rude

Comment: I already use DataFormatString "<asp:BoundField HeaderText="WorkFrom" DataField="WorkFrom" ReadOnly="true" DataFormatString="{0:t}" />"  But anyway if i type a datetime without ":" then i get an error. And what do you mean about inviting to use something else?

Comment: Modified my question to show you the correct format string to use to get a time string without the : separator. See the end of the codeblock. And I was referring to steve behavior who kept inviting you to use something else (asp.net mvc). The format string is for display, you don't need to remove the : in your sql table.

Comment: Ah understood =) and thanks for Formating info, i ll notice it. But  its not exactly what i need. Maybe i asked wrong because of my bad english. I did a picture with completely explaining, take please a quick look. http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/11111.1414634343.jpg but a gridview must show the values as usual "with :", i just have a problem by inserting the data

Comment: Ah I understand The problem is not how it displays in the datagridview but that you can't type 15 00 instead of 15:00 in the detailsview. That's a bit more difficult to answer without knowing your setup - your gridview is bound directly to the database. So you need to either intercept an event generated by the detailsview and modify the data in code behind or to use a custom class as a middle layer between your code and the database and your gridview bind to that middle layer which then transform your string into a valid date for the database.

Comment: sad. I think its too difficult for me at the moment, I will do it after things which are more important. Anyway thanks for showing a right way =) I learn and notice to me all things to do and all my imagination, so if it's not so important i think it doesnt worth to play around this thing for many hours )